# Is "instant explosion" patched in Rare Replay Blast Corps?

Tags: rare-replay, blast-corps

Blast Corps used to have this bug/cheat/feature where buildings would explode when the player attempted to exit and a building was in the way. It isn't working on Oyster Harbor when I try it with the bulldozer. Was it patched or am I doing it wrong?